# What is a good game for showing off OOP in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, oop, inheritance, polymorphism, game-development

For my exam project in coding class I have to recreate a game in Unity where I can also show off my OOP knowledge. Some of the requirements of the project are encapsylation, inheritance and polymorphism.

What are some good ideas for a game that can show all these things? The ideas I had was Candy Crush, Street Fighter, Hearthstone or some tower defense, though I'm not sure if I'll be able to make good use of OOP in these games.

Answer (score 2):

All games you're listing aren't really fit for an exam project. I don't know how much time you have to finish this project, but I'd go with something a lot easier, especially if you're going to do it youself. If the main objective is to use your OOP knowledge, any simple game with maybe different kind of enemies or items will do.
For instance, asteorid, but with other kind of objects and weapons beside the asteroids and the main gun themeselves. Asteorids, bombs, fire balls, you name them. All of them must have some degree of common behavior and that's where OOP can be used. Weapons too. Rayguns, double barrels, radial shots, shockwaves...

This is just an idea. You can do something different like Pac-Man and implement diver kinds of ghosts, for instance. Or different main characters with different abilities.

Although, be aware that Unity (and most other game engines) although built on topo of OO languages prefer a Component-driven approach and true OOP is used in very little quantities in very specific parts of the game. Usually data structures more than game objects.

Comment: Make an Super Mario or any RPG system that will have all things about OOP I believe.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas! This is a 10-week exam project. I'm planning to aim for something quite challenging yet in which can show off OOP in a good way (I'm aiming for highest grade), but yes I assume my suggestions might not be the most fitting for that. I'll think more about the idea of a game where things like inheritance could be used through differens weapons and such. I know it'll be challenging to use a lot of OOP through Unity, but as I said I want a good challenge.

Answer (score 0):

I had a client ask me to build a Tamagotchi type of game and characters are a place where you can use a lot of inheritance to build some base character types then branch off into specific character types. The classic base "animal" and then "bear"/"wolf" etc or biped/quadruped etc some lay eggs, others are mammals you could come up with some good inheritance trees.
In Unity, the different types would need to implement their different ways of triggering animations via the Animator controllers possibly. Most of the systems in Unity won't need any inheritance though, your plain C# classes would implement these and I don't recommend that you build off of Monobehavior. Instead, you have a ScriptableObject and it will instantiance the necessary C# class possibly based on an enum you have that represents all the different types.

Basically it was a 3D Unity Project (nothing used 2D components) and had a simple plane as the ground, and then the camera was above - pointing down at the "ground". The character had 2D art that was perpendicular to the overhead camera, but they were correctly upright with the normal Z world direction so their "feet" were on the ground plane and normal physics/rigidbody can be turned on. This way you can add a Navmesh to the ground and Nav Agents to your characters making movement really simple. They move around like normal, but their art is facing upwards towards the camera. You can give them colliders and rigidbodies. Setting this up took barely any time and saves you from having to work in pure 2D mode with all the problems it comes with for implementing your own movement and control systems, collision detection, etc. If you go pure 2D you lose a lot of systems and it's not necessary. This way you can just use simple 2D art assets.

Your tower defense is also not a bad idea because towers can have inheritance too. Again, design your own classes and you shouldn't be inheriting from Monobehavior in your base class. You aren't expanding on Monobehavior, you are building your own classes.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! Yes I was also thinking about the fact that I probably shouldn't use Monobehavior too much, though itäll be hard at first because I'm so used to it. I did like the idea of doing something more animal-focused, as it opens many possibilites for variation and inheritance. The problem would probably be to find good assets for it (I'm no graphic designer to say the least). I did have the idea of using ScriptableObject, and I was considering using it maybe in a card game if that would work (?). Also, the Tamagotchi sounded fun, I hope it went well!